# Android mx tv box stuck at mbox logo

Tags: boot, unbricking

My Android TV box always gets stuck at the Mbox, "make your life colorful" logo, but it never goes to home screen, and also when I put the TV box into recovery mode I can't select anything, it just shows the dead robot with the words, no command. How can I recover the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the firmware, extract it to a 4g sd card, insert it into your box then press and hold the button in the av hole at the back of the box, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVaczQt6FvBdWxBdEh3amVTZVU&authuser=0).

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, I did not expect the reset button might have been in that hole. Your link is not working anymore. Is there any *official* source where the firmware can be downloaded?